# My Ubuntu Crashed, can't log into the system, what went wrong?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, session

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I did this :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And when I rebooted the system, I couldn't log into the system.

When I proceed with the user name and password I get a small pop-up saying :

```
Failed to load session Gnome  ( Log Out )
```

What went wrong? Are there any ways there to get back to my previous state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you installed with `apt-get` ? And did you try to start with Unity instead of Gnome ?

Comment: @NorTicUs: Nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was a dependency problem which was fixed by removing gnome session with the command `sudo apt-get -f install`. So, you can't log into gnome session.

Try Login in the Unity session. Click on the Ubuntu Logo next to your user name and change it to "Ubuntu"

After login, you can repair some of the missing packages by using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I can see only two option. One is `Ubuntu` and another one is `Ubuntu 2D`. There is no such thing called `Unity`

Comment: @batman that is Ubuntu actually.

Comment: Yes doing so I can able to login. But I lost my look and feel. Are there any way to recover from here?

Comment: You can right click on the desktop and select "Ambiance" as the theme

Comment: When I do `ctrl+alt+t` is not opening terminal! And also I couldn't find any theme named Ambiance in Appearance section.

Comment: @batman hit `ctrl alt f1` to bring up a terminal (actually a tty). After you finish your work on that terminal, you can hit `ctrl alt f7` to go back to the gui mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When did `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. I get an error as : `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Comment: @batman Please ask another question about this new problem. Also describe shortly about this previous problem.

Comment: @A.S.: I got back my desktop. As far as the error is concerned I'm not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstal gnome, this world fix corrupted stuff. Just go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

After the process completes, you will be able to log in to gnome sessions. I had the same problem today with the `-f` option of `apt-get`, and fixed it this way.

Comment: I'm getting unable to locate the package ` gnome-desktop`

Comment: Replace it with ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Or `gnome-shell` for gnome. There is no package named gnome-desktop, my bad, sorry.